# Detener ejecución de for según ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un ajax dentro de un for, tengo que esperar que el ajax responda para poder seguir con la ejecución normal del ciclo. Me ha funcionado con el async:false pero esto congela la página ¿hay otra forma de hacerlo sin usar async?

Comment: Seria mas facil si compartieras tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías quitar el for, meter la llamada Ajax en una fucníon, tener una variable contador y cada vez que termine de hacer un ajax en el response, volver a llamar la función hasta que el contador sea el que tu quieras.

Ejemplo:

```
iniciarAjax();
contador = 0;
function iniciarAjax()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
    success: function(respuesta) {
        contador++;
        if(contador < 5)
        {
          iniciarAjax();
        }
        else
        {
         //Seguir con la fucnón que quieras
         }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
    }
  });
}
```

No sé si queda claro...